# Como fazer apenas uma parte de um objeto crescer, e não o objeto todo?

Tags: construct-2

Teria como fazer, por exemplo, o nariz do Pinóquio crescer quando ele pegasse uma moeda? O objeto é o Pinóquio, e ao pegar a moeda apenas o nariz dele cresceria (um crescimento localizado, entenderam?)

No Construct 2.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Pelo pouco que entendo de software e pelo nada que entendo de construct-2, acho que o que você precisa é de no mínimo dois objetos: um para representar o nariz e outro para representar o restante do pinóquio.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte separar duas sprites, uma do nariz e outra do corpo do pinoquio. Depois Colocar `Behaviour Pin` no Nariz e ao carregar o layout o Nariz vai Pinar na outra parte.

A partir disso você vai setar uma `Origin Point` na base da Sprite do Nariz que ao corpo tocar na moeda, a Sprite do nariz terá que crescer na largura + tantos porcento...

Não sei qual a base de medida que você vai usar, mas pode fazer ele crescer vamos supor 10% a cada moeda.

Pra isso você vai colocar uma variável local no nariz.